# Sign In with Apple in Android + Flutter

Tags: android, flutter, firebase-authentication, sign-in-with-apple

I am developing the Flutter app, where there is an option for Sign with Apple for both - Android and iOS users. I have used [sign_in_with_apple: ^4.3.0](https://pub.dev/packages/sign_in_with_apple) for that. This is working fine for iOS. but in Android, I am facing an error :

> Unable to process request due to missing initial state. This may happen if browser sessionStorage is inaccessible or accidentally cleared.

I tried to run the app on emulator and real device both. But didn't work for me. Can you please share what's wrong or what needs to be update to solve this error?

Comment: Please check this manifest file for android. matches your manifest or not. this file is from their example : https://github.com/aboutyou/dart_packages/blob/master/packages/sign_in_with_apple/sign_in_with_apple/example/android/app/src/main/AndroidManifest.xml

Comment: Yes, I cross-verify that and try one more time, by uninstalling and re-installing the app. still not working.

Comment: From their github page : https://github.com/aboutyou/dart_packages/issues/367 
 and https://github.com/aboutyou/dart_packages/issues/338 
seems like you are missing intent callback for Android.

Comment: I have already added Intent callback in AndroidManifest file. Need to add somewhere else ?

Comment: main mainifest file or debug one ?

Comment: main AndroidManifest (android > app > src > main > AndroidManifest )

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/253604/discussion-between-hardik-mehta-and-khyati-modi).

Answer (score 0):

you need set default browser is chrome，or else it can't analyze intend order